# Passing command to Admin Powershell after opening Powershell from script

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Through the Command Prompt, I am looking to open Powershell as Admin and pass a command for it to execute. The command is simple: remove all .txt files in a directory. I am having a difficult time passing this command into the Admin Powershell. Here's what I'm trying:

`powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs | Remove-Item -Path C:\MyFolder\*.txt"`

So far, the Powershell window opens but nothing is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

You are just piping the `$null` output of `Start-Process` to `Remove-Item`, which makes no sense.

## Solution

Your 2nd Powershell invocation should use `-Command` parameter:

```
powershell -command Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList @('-Command', 'Remove-Item', \"'C:\MyFolder\*.txt'\")
```

The command-line that follows `-command` doesn't need to be quoted, which simplifies nested quoting.

The somewhat strange looking quoting for the `Remove-Item` argument is required to support path with spaces. First the backslash-escaped double quotes will be resolved by the cmd parser, finally the `Remove-Item` call will look like this:

```
Remove-Item 'C:\MyFolder\*.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell -Command  "start-process powershell -Verb RunAs -Args 'Remove-Item -Path C:\MyFolder\*.txt'"
```

you can also pass remove-item as args in string format